# Qual origem da palavra "pelada"?

Tags: significado, origem-histórica, origem

Observem a frase abaixo:

> -Hoje tem pelada as 18:00. Não esquece de levar a chuteira.

No Brasil esse termo é muito usado para referir ao futebol, seja de salão ou de campo.

Qual origem da palavra "pelada"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo o blog Gol de Canela FC do site Lance, não há uma origem definida. Poderia ter origem no latim de péla (*pilella em latim*) sendo o diminutivo de bola ou até mesmo pela falta de grama existente nos campos onde se praticava futebol de forma amadora.

> A palavra pelada é o nome dado aqui no Brasil a uma partida amigável
>   de futebol com regras livres, normalmente sem a preocupação com
>   tamanhos de campo, condição dos equipamentos e uniformes, marcações
>   básicas, entre outros aspectos, ao contrário do futebol profissional.
>
> Com objetivo lúdico, a pelada é o grau mais diversificado do futebol,
>   podendo ser praticada em qualquer espaço que permita a movimentação de
>   dois os mais jogadores de cada time.
>
> Sobre a origem do nome, existem algumas versões para a existência
>   deste termo. Porém, na etimologia, estudo da origem e da evolução das
>   palavras, acredita-se que a palavra possa ter sido derivada do latim,
>   associada a uma metáfora já absorvida no uso comum da língua. “Pelada
>   tem origem controversa, talvez de péla, do Latim pilella, diminutivo
>   de pila, bola, novelo de lã. Pode ter havido mistura com pelo, pois as
>   primeiras bolas eram de couro cru, com pelos. Designando jogo de
>   futebol desorganizado, formou-se por catacrese: nos campos onde era e
>   é praticado falta grama, sobretudo em lugares como a pequena área, que
>   parece pelada. Dá-se catacrese quando uma palavra, à falta de uma
>   outra específica, supre esta falta, como em perna da mesa”, afirma
>   Deonísio da Silva, professor, escritor e etimologista brasileiro.
>
> Assim, independente das versões populares, o termo pelada no futebol
>   nada tem a ver com mulher nua, como muitos acreditavam.

Fonte: http://blogs.lance.com.br/gol-de-canela-fc/qual-e-origem-da-palavra-pelada-no-futebol/